# execute task once when variable is changed

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-swarm

I have playbook which looking for specific container on servers (whole environment), then get docker id container on servers which has desirable service. Last step is exec bash command inside of container. My code:

```
    shell: docker ps | grep '{{service}}:' 
    register: ps
    changed_when: ps.stdout != ""

  - name: get id container with {{service}}
    shell: docker ps | grep '{{service}}:' | awk '{print $1}'
    register: id
    when:  ps is changed

  - name: alembic upgrade head exec
    shell: docker exec -i {{id.stdout}} bash -c 'pwd'
    register: pwd
    when: id is changed
  - debug: var=pwd.stdout_lines
    when: id is changed
```

Output:

```
PLAY [dev2] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dev2_3]
ok: [dev2_4]
ok: [dev2_1]

TASK [search server with graphql] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dev2_1]
changed: [dev2_3]
changed: [dev2_4]

TASK [get id container with graphql] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [dev2_1]
changed: [dev2_3]
changed: [dev2_4]

TASK [alembic upgrade head exec] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [dev2_1]
changed: [dev2_3]
changed: [dev2_4]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [dev2_1]
ok: [dev2_3] => {
    "pwd.stdout_lines": [
        "/usr/src/app"
    ]
}
ok: [dev2_4] => {
    "pwd.stdout_lines": [
        "/usr/src/app"
    ]
}
```

The problem is if you have a group of hosts that has 10 servers, desirable service will be on 5 servers, on above configuration it will executed five times.

What I need: Last task it should be execute one time, on any server which meets the conditions "id is changed"

`run_once: yes` always execute task on first host from the list, so this is random if first host will have desirable status it will executed properly, if not playbook will end with error - first host doesn't have desirable variable (id.stdout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your first challenge is finding the hosts on which your service is running. I might use Ansible's `group_by` module to create a dynamic group of hosts that match your criteria, like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: check host for target service
      become: true
      command: "docker ps --filter name={{ service }} --format '{%raw%}{{{%endraw%} .ID }}'"
      register: service_check

    - set_fact:
        has_target_service: "{{ not (not service_check.stdout) }}"
        container_id: "{{ service_check.stdout }}"

    - group_by:
        key: "has_service_{{ has_target_service }}"
```

This will create two groups, `has_service_True` for hosts that are running your target service and `has_service_False` for hosts that are not. It will also set a `container_id` fact on hosts that are running your target service.

You can then write a new play to handle the database update, and you can use the `run_once` directive to ensure that it only runs on a single host:

```
- hosts: has_service_True
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: alembic upgrade head exec
      run_once: true
      shell: docker exec -i {{container_id}} bash -c 'alembic upgrade command'
```

**Answers to comments**

1. The problem is that syntax used for formatting in Docker is the same syntax used for Jinja expressions in Ansible.  So if you write `{{ something }}`, Ansible will try to interpret that as a Jinja expression. Using `{%raw}...{%endraw%}` allows us to write `{{` in a way that it won't be captured by Ansible.
2. I wrote `{{ not (not service_check.stdout) }}` because `service_check.stdout` is a string, and I wanted a boolean. An empty string evaluated as a boolean is `false`, and a non-empty string is `true`.  Ergo, the expression `not service_check.stdout` would be `false` if `stdout` has content and `true` if it is empty.  I wanted the opposite of that, so we negate the expression again.

   Honestly, I could have written instead `{{ true if service_check.stdout else false }}`, which is probably more clear.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Can you explain me a few things?
1. why you add `{%raw%}{{{%endraw%}` to first task, in docker syntax it would enough `"{{.ID}}"`
2. How works `has_target_service: "{{ not (not service_check.stdout) }}"` fact?

Comment: Glad to help! I've added answers to your questions to my answer.